# Angular - Some Attributes Need Explicit Binding to $scope, Others Don't?

Tags: angularjs

Here is some code that works (glancing it is enough):

```
<div ng-repeat = "n in lotteryNumbers" ng-if="doShowExample">
    <input type="text" value = "{{lotteryNumbers[n]}}"></input>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.doShowExample = true;
            $scope.lotteryNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
        });
</script>
```

We see two attributes here that have values assigned:

```
ng-if="doShowExample"
```

and

```
value = "{{lotteryNumbers[n]}}"
```

I don't really understand the logic behind one attribute's value needing to be put into curly braces(ng-model) to be bound and the other not. Why does it sometimes automatically know that your are looking for a variable rather than an explicit value?

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PPifKMN0xb0bqkc7IYTl?p=preview) if you want it, but nothing interesting there. Just here in case I am wrong and you want to show me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `value` is not an *angular directive* but it is just an attribute of the element which can be assigned a value, it has not idea what an angular expression is. So providing an interpolation ('{{...}}') on an expression results in the assignment of the result of expression to the value of text box. But you rarely would need to do this if at all you need to provide value as is you could use angular directive `ng-value` as well.

```
   <input type="text" ng-value= "lotteryNumbers[n]"></input>
```

But most cases you need an `ng-model` for 2-way binding.

```
   <input type="text" ng-model= "lotteryNumbers[n]"></input>
```

So in short

> {{AngularExpression_XYZ}} --> Value of AngularExpression_XYZ

When you see an angular directive that expects an expression you need to provide the expression itself, for ex - `ng-if, ng-repeat, ng-show` and many more..... But if you see something takes a value for example: `ng-attr-x`you need to provide some value to it, which you do it via interpolation.

Now coming to what you have in your example you are doing it wrong by doing `lotteryNumbers[n]` where `n` from the ng-repeat expression (`"n in lotteryNumbers"`) in your case is not the index but it is the value itself. But since you have array of numbers and you expect `ng-model` to work properly with the array of ng-repeat you may try using `$index` and also you would need to use track by expression itself since it will end up losing the focus on the textbox as the array gets updated.

```
<div ng-repeat = "n in lotteryNumbers track by $index" ng-if="doShowExample">
    <input type="text" ng-value = "lotteryNumbers[$index]"></input>
    <input type="text" ng-model = "lotteryNumbers[$index]"></input>
</div>
```

But in real usecase you should try to avoid this and bind it to array of objects in order to avoid such issues.

Comment: I didn't realize I could use ng-model like that for some odd, odd reason. Thank you, I will accept when the timer runs down.

Comment: @VSO You are welcome. Here is your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/cageWC0KBd0PRKkCK6q5?p=preview

Comment: haha, now I have to look up details on 'track by $index', never used that before either. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @VSO :) look up ng-repeat documentation.

Comment: Yup, will do. /min post length

Answer (score 1):

In your example

```
ng-if
```

Is a angular directive that you pass a scope variable to.

```
value
```

Is a standard html attribute -> it cant take in scope variable. It can only handle "values" so you have to use {{var}}.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am accepting PSL's answer due to details, but I appreciate yours.